# Entity Framework 3 - Filter Elements in Chained Navigational Properties

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to limit the elements selected in a series of navigational chains.  Here's roughly the sequence:
Order -> Preference(s) -> PreferenceCard -> Item(s) -> OrderItem

Notes:

- An order can have multiple preferences.
- A preference has 1 preference card.
- A preference card is comprised of items.
- An OrderItem contains details about that item specific to the order.

How do I restrict the selection of OrderItems to only those linked to my order?  My `Include("Preference.PreferenceCard.Item.OrderItem")` just grabs all OrderItems, even if they don't correspond to the Order.

I've tried a `Where()` clause, but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
.Where(
    o => o.Preference.Any(
        p => p.PreferenceCard.Items.Any(
            item => item.OrderItem.Any(
                orderItem => orderItem.OrderId == o.OrderId))))
```

How can I properly filter the OrderItems by OrderId even chained through navigational properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the main source of confusion with these types of problems is understanding that an Entity from EntityFramework is different than just a normal class. If you don't want to manipulate your data structure or its navigation properties (add, modify, delete) and you just want to have a custom view of your data than you should be returning an anonymous type or a POCO (Plain Old CLR Objects). You can declare your own class and assign the properties accordingly.

```
public class OrderView
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
  ...
}

var query = from o in context.Orders
            select new OrderView
            {
              Id = o.Id,
              OrderItems = //custom filtering
              ...
             };
```

Comment: This data will be manipulated, and I don't want to filter the object in memory for performance reasons.  Is there no way to filter the elements grabbed?

Comment: @strongriley - I'm not suggesting you filter the elements in memory. With EntityFramework, filtering your Entities navigation property is the same as removing those items. How are you going to manipulate the data if the Entity has only a fraction of its Navigational property?

Comment: Thanks for the guidance - I ended up grabbing the OrderItems directly off Order then iterating, attaching them back down to the PreferenceCard/Items.